# Is it possible to view T-SQL Commands that SQL Server runs when making changes in SSMS

Tags: t-sql, ssms, sql-server-2014

I would like to view all the sql statements that sql server runs when working with SSMS.

For example when i change the Database Read-Only property of a database to TRUE I suppose the following code runs:

USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET READ_ONLY WITH NO_WAIT
GO

Is there a way to track these kind of commands?

Comment: Are you trying to find out the commands run when you use the GUI? Click the "Script" button.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to find out, and you answered exactly my question. Thank you a lot!